# Solving equivalence relations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A relation R is defined on R such that aRb if and only if  |a−b|< 1. Show that R is reflexive and symmetric but not transitive. Could you explain in detail? I tried reflexivity, but i don't know how to do the rest.

Comment: You tried reflexivity. Did you succeed?

Answer (score 3):

Hint on symmetry:

There is no difference between the distances Amsterdam-Rotterdam and  Rotterdam-Amsterdam.

Hint on transitivity:

If the distance from $A$ to $B$ and the distance from $B$ to $C$ are both less than a mile, then is it necessarily true that the distance from $A$ to $C$ is less than a mile?